# ImportError: cannot import name xls2db

Tags: python, importerror

I installed xls2db using

```
sudo pip install xls2db
```

and when I attempted to try out the sample code provided by the module creator here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xls2db

```
from xls2db import xls2db
xls2db("in.xls", "out.db")
```

I get this error:

ImportError: cannot import name xls2db

Any ideas? I have python 2.7 and I am using pucharm on ubuntu if that matters at all!

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: can you do `import xls2db` or is it throwing an error too? Did `pip install` result in error beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have your own version of `xls2db.py`. It will prevent import of `xls2db` package you have installed.

If there's one, rename the file not to collide with the package. (Remove `xls2db.pyc` if there's one).

Comment: i didn't know about asciicinema. Great idea!

Comment: @falsetru You sir are a magician! I would have never guessed my silly mistake! Thank you!